# Is it possible to use :hover on :first-child:after?

Tags: css, pseudo-class

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div > :first-child:after {
    background-color: orange;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    content: "hello world";
    display: block;
    font-size: 50px;
    height: 160px;   
    line-height: 160px;
    margin-top: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
}
div > :first-child:after:hover {
    background-color: #44b800;
}
```

**Fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/VSBr6/

Basically, all I want to do is change the background-color on hover but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You can't `:hover` a pseudo-class. `:after` and `:before` don't work that way.

Comment: thanks, I thought that was the case but couldn't find anything when searching for the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
div:first-child:hover::after {
    background-color: #44b800;
}
```