# Hover over parent div to load child:after. Css sprite transition

Tags: html, css

Can I hover over a parent div to alter a child div :after. This is so I can transition sprites.

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15704955/is-it-possible-to-use-hover-on-first-childafter) on here.

I am unsure of the formatting due to these being classes.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4dvpz5md/) to see what I am trying to achieve.

```css
.project-button {
  position: relative;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;    
  width: 31.555%;  
  color: #a4afbc;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .2s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .2s ease;
  -o-transition: all .2s ease;
  transition: all .2s ease;
}

.project-button:hover {
  border-left: 0;
  color: #343434;
}

.button-previous {
  position:relative;
  display: inline-block;
  text-indent: -9999px;  
  margin-top: 7.065%;
  margin-bottom: 7.065%;
  padding-top: 39.664%;    
  width: 18%;
  height: auto; 
  background: url(../images/buttons/project-sprite.png) no-repeat top left;
  background-size: 200%;
}

.button-previous:after {
  position: absolute;      
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;

  background: url(../images/buttons/project-sprite.png) no-repeat bottom left;
  background-size: 200%;   
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .2s ease;
  -moz-transition: opacity .2s ease;
  -ms-transition: opacity .2s ease;
  -o-transition: opacity .2s ease;
  transition: opacity .2s ease;
}

.project-button:hover .button-previous:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="project-button">
  <div class="button-previous">
  </div>
  <div class="button-title">
    <h5>Title</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="button-about">
  </div>
  <p>
    <a class="divLink" href="project.html"></a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is your button with class button-previous?

Comment: "Can I hover over a parent div to alter a child div :after." Yes you can. `parent:hover child:after`

Comment: Apologies. I copied the 'next' button (which is the same but a mirror). I have amended the markup to reflect this.

Comment: @Paulie_D What would be the exact formatting for this in regard to my CSS?

Comment: Formatting? Looks to me as though you already have that in your CSS. `.project-button:hover .button-previous:after`. Other than that we probably need to see a brief demo of what the actual issue is.

Comment: This code is a mess, I'm not even sure what it is meant to be... Can you give us a clue on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Ruddy I have a background sprite I want to fade when I hover over the parent div. Hovering over the parent div also changes the colour of the text and borders.

Comment: @Paulie_D I will see if I can put an example up somewhere. Unfortunately that formatting doesn't change the sprite.

Comment: If it's an actual multi-image sprite then it's probably that you haven't used the `background-position` property correctly (if at all). Also, **you cannot affect the opacity of a background-image**

Comment: Hey @Paulie_D I have just made a JSFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/4dvpz5md/
The multi-sprite image has been working. It is when I attempt to use opacity to create a smooth transition that I altered the css and it doesn't seem to work. Can you recommend the best formatting?

Comment: @Paulie_D I used this tutorial to create this. Here you can use opacity. http://css-tricks.com/fade-image-within-sprite/

Comment: @lagmonster [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5v7c9nkz/), just made this example to show you it can be done (don't want to work with your messy code). For that matter, now looking at your fiddle isn't this what you want? [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dvpz5md/1/)

Comment: @Ruddy Yes that is what I am after. Is it just the content part that has been added. Can I ask what is messy about it? (since I did a minor tidy)

Comment: @lagmonster Yes, you was missing `content: "";`. And the messy parts for me are the percentages and the border parts. Then again, I'm pretty picky.

Comment: @Paulie_D Just incase you wanted to see what the OP was talking about check out the last few comments.

Comment: @Ruddy But I thought it is recommended to switch to percentages? And as I wish it to be an exact size via scaling this is why the number is so long.

Comment: @lagmonster I mean that you have them so precise and even for the borders. I find that messy. You are correct tho, percentages are they way to go.